# How to computer complex Matrix derivative

Tags: matrix-calculus

I want to solve following minimization problem using lagrange multipliers... i have problem computing derivatives w.r.t complex matrx K .. can anybody do it?

$$\min_K  \quad trace(KRK^{H}) \qquad \text{s.t. } KH=I $$

Thanks

Comment: What is $H$?  What does $H^H$ stands for?  Since you have a constraint $KH = I$, then the objective is reduced to $H^H$.  But is $H^H$ is scalar or a matrix?

Comment: I have rephrased the question,,,all of these are matrices, $K^H$ is hermitian i.e, conjugate transpose of $K$ and $H$ can be any matrix.

Comment: But still, the expression $KRK^H$ is a matrix.  What do you mean by minimizing a matrix?

Comment: Assume we want to minimise the trace of the matrix..